# loadbalancing and replication in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a Multi-Master-Slave Setup with 2 Master and 1 Slave. I'd like to have all the reads only on the Slave and loadbalanced (round robin) writes.

There is a solution for Replication:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html

and a solution for Loadbalancing:
  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-managing-load-balanced-connections.html

I'm using the standard *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver* for the connection Object.
The connection String looks like this:

```
String URL = "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master),address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3307)(type=master),address=(protocol=tcp)(host=localhost)(port=3308)(type=slave)/test?"
      + "characterEncoding=UTF-8";
```

If using the loadbalance solution everything (reads and writes) gets distributed. If using *jdbc:mysql:replication:* the writes always goes to the first Master and the reads are always being answered by the Slave.

Is there a way to configure JDBC to satisfy my requirements? I try to avoid to have 2 connections.

Comment: In what way don't the links you have cited answer your question?

Comment: I don't see any possibility to have both: Replication + Loadbalancing in one connection. The links show only a specific solution to one of those. Maybe you are right and the docs show that this is not possible (because it is not documented) and I have to write a little wrapper.

Comment: I haven't said anything to be right about, I simply asked you a question. But doesn't [`jdbc:mysql://address=(type=master)(host=master1host),address=(type=master)(host=master2host),address=(type=slave)(host=slave1host)/database`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html) do exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, but it didn't loadbalanced the reads. I guess the default com.mysql.jdbc.Driver did not parse the query, therefore the driver can't decide and always goes directly to the master

Comment: I doubt it. The same parser would be used for all configurations. Your comment implies that it never used the slaves at all: is that really true?

Comment: My tests came up with this strange behaviour: If using neither _loadbalance_ nor _replication_ in the connection string all queries are going to the first! configured server. Regardless if the first one is of type slave. Maybe this is a bug? Or my test is to simple (just doing some 100 SELECTS and INSERTS in a loop, always with a new connection object).

Comment: Did you set `readOnly` for the queries?

Comment: No, that wouldn't fit my requirements. I don't want to change the app code. If I would using the readOnly option I have to refactor far too much. The app will be replaced in the near future, so I don't want waste too much time.

Comment: It won't use the slave unless you set `readOnly`. Says so.

Comment: Ok. Thanks so far. You helped me alot understanding thinks better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not possible with the J/Connector (and actually this makes sense).

I'll use a Proxy Solution like MaxScale which you can use in a Master/Slave and in a Cluster environment.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work it is crucial to set the jdbc connections to read only.